# heroku multiple web process

Tags: heroku

Is it possible to run 2 different web process in one instance, like

`for /url1/ some process`

and

`for /url2/ another`

or some port manipulation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple worker/web processes on a single heroku app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22989339/multiple-worker-web-processes-on-a-single-heroku-app)

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has the concept of [Dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos). They can roughly be thought of as processes.

It is possible for multiple processes to run under each Dyno. Requests are load balanced by Heroku. No special configuration is required.

For example, the [Unicorn web server](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/) can be configured to spawn "worker" processes. Each "worker" serves a HTTP request. So, if you configure Unicorn to have 3 workers, 2 Dynos would give you 6 processes to serve HTTP requests.

These articles should help you understand how Heroku works:

- [Dynos and the Dyno Manifold](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos)
- [The Process Model](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/process-model)

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question. He seems to be asking about using different servers to serve different URLs