# One Heroku worker process for both delayed_job and sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq

Currently our Heroku app has two dynos: web and worker. The worker dyno is set up to run `bundle exec rake jobs:work`, which starts up delayed_job. I have some new Sidekiq jobs that I also need to run. (I plan to convert our delayed_job jobs to Sidekiq soon, but haven't yet.) My question is: do I need to add and pay for a third Heroku dyno ("sidekiqworker"?), or is there a way for me to specify that my existing worker dyno run both delayed_job and Sidekiq?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pay for a third heroku dyno unfortunately. I've experimented with naming both processes as "Workers" but only one would be registered while the other one wouldn't be. When adding a new process name, heroku updates and will set that new process name to 0 dynos.

Refer to this for more details [multiple worker/web processes on a single heroku app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22989339/multiple-worker-web-processes-on-a-single-heroku-app)