# Heroku & Discord.py: Trying to run two bots from same Procfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, discord.py

I have added this Procfile code:

```
worker: python jervis-1.py & python jervis-2.py & wait -n
```

It should run at least one of the bots, but it doesn't run the bot. I don't really know how to fix this error and what all details I should give.
Ask me for any details if you want.

Thanks!

#### Update:

This is the build log of heroku:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
-----> Python app detected
-----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
 !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.9.5
       Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
-----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
-----> Using cached install of python-3.9.3
-----> Installing pip 20.2.4, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.36.2
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> worker
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 80.4M
-----> Launching...
       Released v17
       https://jervis-bots.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Comment: Replace `$` before the `wait -n` with `&`

Comment: @DriftAsimov Oh no! That is horrible unseen error I made. I literally thought the whole time that I have added `&`. TwT

Comment: @DriftAsimov I did that. But still the bots are offline.

Comment: How are you running the bots in each file? Are they completely different bots or same source code and different accounts?

Comment: why not use threading and run them in one file?

Comment: @Ceres They are two bots in different files. Both are from two different applications. But both are from my account itself.

Comment: @chess_lover_6 I don't know about threading! Probably Enlighten me!?

Comment: @BhavyadeepYadav https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-can-i-use-threading-in-python
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905965/creating-threads-in-python

Comment: Could you try changing the name of the process from `worker` to `web`? Only `web` processes can receive HTTP traffic, which your discord bot needs to communicate.  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#the-web-process-type

Comment: @PatrickHaugh It can work anyway you tell me! I don't know how this thing works at all!

Comment: @PatrickHaugh It did not work!

Answer (score 1):

`worker: python -C jervis-1.py & python jervis-2.py & wait -n` should work.

Comment: The bots didn't go online.

Comment: @BhavyadeepYadav is there anything in the logs?

Comment: I have added the log into the question... Please check!

Comment: @BhavyadeepYadav You can check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53233129/how-can-i-run-two-scripts-on-heroku